# How can I read a two-column CSV file, add rows to it, then write it to a new CSV file

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file which, when I import it with 'Import-Csv', looks like this (for example):

```
Animal  Color
-----   -----
Cat     Black
Cat     Calico
Dog     Brown
```

I'm trying to add rows to it - e.g. "Cat   White" - but I can't figure out how. 'Import-Csv' defaults to an array that looks multi-dimensional, but it behaves like a regular array, so that if I do "$csv += 'cat','white'", for example, it puts both items in the 'Animal' column.

I tried converting the array to a hash table instead, but that won't fly because hash table keys must be unique and I have "Cat" in there twice (and will need to add more "Cat" rows later anyway).

Then I tried doing it as a hash table with unique keys and with arrays as values, so that I end up with something like this:

```
Name   Value                                                                                                                                       
----   -----                                                                                                                                       
Cats   {Black, Calico}                                                                                                                
Dogs   {Brown}
```

Okay, that sort of works, since I can now add values to those arrays correctly, create more key/value pairs, etc. But now I'm stuck trying to figure out how to export that back to a two-column CSV.

So now I'm stumped! Is there a more straightforward way of doing this? If not, can you help me figure out how to properly export that second type of hash table to a simple, two-column CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read in the file as csv, each row is an object. To add another object, you have to create one first then append to the existing csv import.

```
$csv = import-csv file.csv
$csv += New-Object PsObject -Property @{ Animal= 'Cat' ; Color = 'White' }
...

# Add more objects and once you are done updating the csv, save the updated data
$csv | Export-Csv C:\temp\newFile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

`-NoTypeInformation` is used to omit the type information saved to csv file.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed. No need to mess with hash tables at all. Thanks!

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is quite expensive in processing terms. You should import the data, do all manipulation then only write back to csv as a final step, not after each object

Comment: @Scepticalist - Good to know. It won't be an issue for this particular script, but I'll keep that in mind for larger data sets. Thanks!

Comment: As per [@Scepticalist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6203113/scepticalist) comment, the correct way is using the PowerShell pipeline: `import-csv file.csv; New-Object PsObject -Property @{ Animal= 'Cat' ; Color = 'White' } | Export-Csv C:\temp\newFile.csv -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: @iRon not unless you have multiple objects you intend to add. You can pipe it to Export-Csv like you mentioned above but if you have multiple objects you intend to add, you probably want to update the csv before exporting it to new file.

Comment: Then it is: `import-csv file.csv; 1..3 | ForEach-Object {New-Object PsObject -Property @{ Animal= 'Cat' ; Color = 'White' }} | Export-Csv`